# Chrome extension clone element with its event listeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension to interact with a website I don't own.

This website has a bug that is causing accidental removal of a button from the website's DOM, after another action, and I have to reload the page again in order for it to show up again.

I contacted the website about it, they confirmed it's a bug, but, apparently it's not a priority for them to fix it, so, I want to fix this issue within my extension.

**So, what I was thinking of is:**

1. Clone the original button once the page loads, and hide the cloned DOM element (as a backup).
2. Listen to the removal of the button, and once it's removed, I show my backup button.

### The problem is:

This button event listeners are triggering back-end request, so, I can't re-create them in the DOM on my own, I have to clone them!

### My question is:

How can I clone the event listeners attached to that button to my backup element when the page first loads?

---

I tried `node.cloneNode(true); // deep copy` and the jQuery [`clone(true)` method](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) as well, but, they didn't work.

Comment: If you use MutationObserver on the element's parent/ancestor you can restore the original removed element which would retain its listeners, arguably.

Comment: @wOxxOm This sounded like a good idea to me at the beginning, however, when I tried it, I discovered that the button gets mutated by the website before it's eventually removed (they disable it and change its status to a loading status), so, when I try to restore it from inside the MutationObserver's callback, it's returned at its last status before the removal (returned mutated/disabled)! I tried to change its status after restoring it, however, the event listeners weren't there!

Comment: I also tried to assign the button to a variable after the page loads, and restore it from that variable (after the original button is removed), however, surprisingly it's returned mutated/disabled/event listeners stripped as well! even though I assigned it to the variable while its status was normal.

Answer (score 0):

I admire your idea of copying DOM and listener, but I have another idea.

**With extension, can try to replace origin script content to your content which is repaired  by you.**

open https://0g3hpx.csb.app/ in your chrome and launch this extension in your chrome develop mode, you can see script is replace by extension.
[code here:fix-button-removed-by-accident-extension](https://cdn.sm.cn/static/23/03/03/04786e65ed2327cd0237b67160964b93.zip)

## Main process

1. add fixed bundle-fix.js to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
2. add permissions in manifest.json
3. add addListener before request and replace origin website's script source.
4. copy script source and fix the problem
5. launch extension as you know
   Here are some main code.

```
/// background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function() {
    return { redirectUrl:chrome.extension.getURL('resource-redirect/bundle-fix.js')}; 
  },
  {
    urls: ["https://0g3hpx.csb.app/bundle.js"],  

    types: ["script"]       
  },
  ["blocking"] 
);
```

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "fix-button-removed-by-accident",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "fix-button-removed-by-accident",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "resource-redirect/bundle-fix.js"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "idle",
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "storage",
    "contextMenus",
    "https://0g3hpx.csb.app/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": []
}
```